# Multiple Pendulums and Resonance

Tags: frequency, resonance, vibrations

Set up with multiple pendulums suspended from a connecting string. Pendulums 1 and 4 have the same lengths and hence, the same natural frequencies. Others(pendulums 2, 3 and 5) are of varying frequencies.

[image: Set up with multiple pendulums suspended from a connecting string. Pendulums 1 and 4 have the same lengths and hence, the same natural frequencies. Others(pendulums 2, 3 and 5) are of varying frequencies.]

Pendulum 1 is brought into motion. (It starts oscillating with its natural frequency ƒ.)
The vibrations are transmitted to the connecting string. Immediately after this,

- does the connecting string vibrate at frequency ƒ(forced vibrations)?
- does it vibrate at its own natural frequency and then slowly acquire frequency ƒ(forced vibrations)?

> natural frequency of string = 1/(2L) √(T/μ). I am aware that plucking strings at different points alters their frequency.

Next, these vibrations travel to all the other pendulums. Immediately after this, what happens to the pendulums 2, 3 and 5?

- do these pendulums oscillate at their natural frequency throughout the process?
- do these pendulums begin with their natural frequency and slowly acquire frequency ƒ (forced vibrations) and maintain this throughout the process?
- do these pendulums begin with frequency ƒ (forced vibrations) and then maintain this throughout the process?

> natural frequency of pendulum = √(g/l)

The vibrations also transmit to pendulum 4 which has a natural frequency ƒ. Resonance occurs as the periodic force driving pendulum 4 is also at frequency f and the amplitude of pendulum 4 increases. When it is oscillating at its maximum amplitude, pendulum 1 is oscillating at its minimum amplitude. Is this called being "out of phase" or is "out of phase" something entirely different?

I feel like I'm entirely wrong about numerous concepts here. Please correct me on finding any such errors.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There are good answers to your question, but they are easier to study on a linear and better defined system made of point masses connected by springs. See e.g. http://www.physics.hmc.edu/~saeta/courses/p111/uploads/Y2013/chap13.pdf

Comment: For a mathematical model, you need to add some details about the constraint of the horizontal bar to the ground. Maybe a first model could be a rigid bar, with its horizontal motion as the only dof, with one of its extremity connected to the ground with a linear spring.
Meanwhile, you can take a look at frequency synchronization of coupled oscillators http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Synchronization

Comment: @basics thank you.. the article on synchronization was helpful. I understand phase better now. Apparently, in most web pages about Barton's Pendulums, the pendulum at resonance is 90° behind the driver which means when the driver is at its extreme, the pendulum at resonance is at its mean. (crest of one wave corresponds to the midpoint of another wave)
I am still unsure whether, in this example, the resonating pendulums would be out of phase by 90° or some other angle.

Comment: maybe later I can find time to write an answer, if nobody answers before. btw, scholarpedia has some good references for many topics